# on NSTimer interval, UITableView.visibleCells wrong response

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using NSTimer with 1.1 seconds interval, the timer fires properly, but (mostly) on scrolling `UITableView.visibleCells` does not update the response, the response contains invisible cells.

Below is my Swift code

```
private func onApiResponse() {
    _timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.1, target: self, selector: "myTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

above timer after backend api response

```
func myTimer() {
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `tableView.visibleCells` should always give you the correct result, so the issue might be your table view's height is larger than it's super view's height, so some of the cells are not showing on the screen, but they are "visible" to the tableview

Comment: @Eric Qian, yes it should, but it doesnt, and table view height is also within its superview bounds

Answer (score 1):

here is the fix that worked in my case.

Instead to get visible cells using `tableView.visibleCells`, I get a list of indexPaths using `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows` with `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath`, below is the sample code:

```
if let paths = mode == 0 ? tvList.indexPathsForVisibleRows : tvGallery.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
    for path in paths {
        if let isNotNil = moProducts[path.row].data where moProducts[path.row].bidValid {
            if let cell = (mode == 0 ? tvList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path) : tvGallery.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path)) as? SubClassCell {
                // do something here with the cell
            }
        }
    }
}
```